# Supersized full-screen slider with vertical thumb-tray

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, slider, supersized

I have Jquery supersized fullscreen slider with default shutter theme as my wordpress theme slider . Default Thumbnail container for this slider is horizontal at bottom of the screen. Is anyone have an idea about how to make this thumb-tray vertically at right of the screen?

Demo link for supersized:- [demo with Horizontal thumb-tray](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html)

Demo link for desired result: [demo with vertical thumb-tray](http://labs.burntfeathers.com/?theme=village)

Answer (score 1):

I found this one based on jQuery (with no conflict mode) very usefull and totaly free: http://www.comslider.com :)

Answer (score 0):

See the following link

Look the 2nd demo

http://www.menucool.com/slider/jquery-slideshow

Other references

http://evoslider.com/demo3.html

Answer (score 0):

In supersized.shuter.js I found the script lines responsible for horizontal movement of thumb tray.

```
/* Thumbnail Mouse Scrub
        ----------------------------*/
        if (api.options.mouse_scrub){
            $(vars.thumb_tray).mousemove(function(e) {
                var containerWidth = $(vars.thumb_tray).width(),
                    listWidth = $(vars.thumb_list).width();
                if (listWidth > containerWidth){
                    var mousePos = 1,
                        diff = e.pageX - mousePos;
                    if (diff > 10 || diff < -10) {
                        mousePos = e.pageX;
                        newX = (containerWidth - listWidth) * (e.pageX/containerWidth);
                        diff = parseInt(Math.abs(parseInt($(vars.thumb_list).css('left'))-newX )).toFixed(0);
                        $(vars.thumb_list).stop().animate({'left':newX}, {duration:diff*3, easing:'easeOutExpo'});
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

With some changes in suersized-shutter.css, I got the vertical thumb tray containing thumbnails.But in this vertical tray my thumb moving horizontally and hiding instead of moving along with vertical thumb-tray height. So suggest me the proper customization if you are familiar with the customization ans setting of supersized slider.